# Update within useEffect not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a web app that just shoots up a bunch of fireworks once a button is pressed.
It's in react and I'm trying to use the useEffect hook to make the fireworks shoot up once the ID variable is updated.
When it renders in the beginning, it works just fine, it shoots up fireworks how I want it to, but the restart button doesn't work. No fireworks are shown after the first time.
By using console.log, I've made sure that the useEffect block is actually being called when the button is pressed and the count changes. I think what is happening is because the container gets declared again, it's not updating when it rerenders? I honestly have no clue, would really appreciate some help <3

```js
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

function App() {
  const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setCount(count+1)
    console.log('button pressed' + count);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('effect called' + count);
    const container = document.getElementById('fireworks-container');
    // Referencing `Fireworks.default` instead of `Fireworks` because Stack Snippets does not support ES6 Modules.
    const fireworks = new Fireworks.default(container);
    fireworks.launch(10);
    fireworks.launch(20);
    makeRequest();
    
    // Using Promise.then because Babel version used by Stack Snippets does not support async/await.
    function makeRequest() {
      return delay(200)
        .then(() => fireworks.launch(20))
        .then(() => delay(300))
        .then(() => fireworks.launch(20));
    }
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className = "text">Fireworks App</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Restart</button>
      <div id = 'fireworks-container' style = {{width: '100%', height: '100vh'}}/>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/fireworks-js@2.x/dist/index.umd.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I was expecting that the fireworks would just appear again since I make a new firework and launch it? I feel like I need to make the firework object outside of the useEffect, but it doesn't work and gives me a bunch of errors.

Comment: My suspicion is since the fireworks object is already "tied" to your container, it doesn't work maybe? If that's the case, you may want to find a way to "detach" an existing fireworks object first.

Comment: Alternatively you might need two `useEffect` blocks, the first constructs the `Fireworks` object once, and then the second launches, reacting to `count`

Comment: It's quite annoying because I'm using the fireworks-js library and their firework object takes in a container as a required argument... ;(
or if there's a quick and easy way to rerender/restart just a specific container?
I've tried just using window.location.reload(); and I guess that works, but I want to keep some local variables in the future as I build the app out.

Comment: @Caleth, do you have any tips on how to make the firework object available in the second useEffect block? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: With a ref or state hook.

Comment: Fireworks.js also has a [component for React](https://github.com/crashmax-dev/fireworks-js/tree/master#fireworks-jsreact). You may be able to use the API from the component to achieve the behaviour you want with less of your own wiring up to do.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what @Caleth suggested in the comments, and it also ended up working, so I will post it here. I made two separate useEffect blocks, where one just initializes the container and the firework object!
Thanks everyone for your help!

```js
import './App.css';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Fireworks from 'fireworks-js';

function App() {

  const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

  const fireworks = useRef();

  useEffect(()=>{
    const container = document.getElementById('fireworks-container');
    fireworks.current = new Fireworks(container);
  }, []);

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setCount(count+1)
    console.log('button pressed' + count);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('effect called' + count);
    fireworks.current.launch(10);
    fireworks.current.launch(20);
    makeRequest();

    async function makeRequest() {
      await delay(200);
      fireworks.current.launch(20);
      await delay(300);
      fireworks.current.launch(20);
    }
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className = "text">Fireworks App</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Restart</button>
      <div id = 'fireworks-container' style = {{width: '100%', height: '100vh'}}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Force React to create a new instance of the fireworks container by giving it a different key value on each render, then use a ref to get a handle on the instance. Since React fully manages the DOM instance, using `getElementById` is not recommended, since you cannot predict when or why React will decide to create a new DOM element. Which is why you use useRef().
Updated code:

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import Fireworks from "fireworks-js";

// this and delay() can be moved to a separate files so that any component
// can launch fireworks or delay something
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function launchFireworks(container) {
  const fireworks = new Fireworks(container);
  fireworks.launch(10);
  fireworks.launch(20);

  await delay(200);
  fireworks.launch(20);
  await delay(300);
  fireworks.launch(20);
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  // container will hold a reference to the node created by React in container.current
  const container = useRef();

  function handleClick() {
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log("button pressed" + count);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect called " + count);
    launchFireworks(container.current);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="text">Fireworks App</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Restart</button>
      <div key={count} ref={container} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```